# Cannot disable safe mode by restarting, how to disable safe mode?

Tags: safe-mode

My Android 10, Nokia 7.1 phone ended up in safe mode. How do I disable this?

Tried restarting and turning off/on as per instructions I've found online but it always starts up in safe mode.

Comment: Is your volume down key responding correctly? Have you had possibly liquids get inside the buttons?

Comment: You could try booting to recovery and clearing cache from there. If your battery is removable, shutting down, removing it and the SIM card for a few minutes, and putting everything together again is also reported to help in some such cases.